# Filter data with it correponding value on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-loc

I have the following datfarame

| ind | Q | haul1 | haul2 | haul3 | haul4 | haul5 | em1 | em2 | em3 | em4 | em5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | medio | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.165850 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | medio | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.244922 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 1 | medio | medio | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.165850 | 0.165850 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 5071 | 3 | medio | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.071119 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Where Q can be 1, 2 or 3 and haul can be corto, medio, largo. Each haul has a correponding em, that depends on the haul give. I want to filter or select only the values that correspond with the hauls 'corto' and with Q '1', while ignoring the hauls 'medio', 'largo' and Q '3' with their corresponding em

I tried .loc with not equal operator to discard the other hauls

```
p=em.loc[((em.Q=='1') & ((em.haul1!='largo') & (em.haul1!='medio') & (em.haul2!='largo') & (em.haul2!='medio') & (em.haul3!='largo') & (em.haul3!='medio') & (em.haul4!='medio') & (em.haul4!='largo') & (em.haul5!='medio') & (em.haul5!='largo')))]
```

but it gives me only the data which initially had only 'corto'

I am trying to make it from

| ind | Q | haul1 | haul2 | haul3 | haul4 | haul5 | em1 | em2 | em3 | em4 | em5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | corto | largo | largo | corto | NaN | 0.042763 | 0.926559 | 0.926559 | 0.042763 | NaN |
| ... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | ... | ... |

To

| ind | Q | haul1 | haul2 | haul3 | haul4 | haul5 | em1 | em2 | em3 | em4 | em5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | corto | NaN | NaN | corto | NaN | 0.042763 | NaN | NaN | 0.042763 | NaN |
| ... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | ... | ... |

So i can sum the values of em with `.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)` and with the condition that the haul is 'corto' and Q '1'.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```python
em[(em.Q == '1') & (em.iloc[:,2:7]!='medio').all(axis=1) & (em.iloc[:,2:7]!='largo').all(axis=1)]
```

2nd and 3rd clause can be combined into one:

```python
em[(em.Q == '1') & (sum((em.iloc[:,2:7]!=(i)).all(axis=1) for i in ('medio', 'largo')) == 2)]
```

Now it's a bit shorter and easier to play with.
This will result in your **to** table. And if you change `== 2` to 1, the result will be as indicated in **from**.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed filters the data, however, it also filters the rows that contains multiple hauls (e.g. medio/corto/medio). I'm looking for a way to remove/replace hauls 'medio' and 'largo' with their respective data without erasing the whole row.

Comment: @JavierSalvador hard to understand. Can you update the question to depict what happens and your desire on what should not happen?